# rxJs Subject, error in subscriptions kills the whole stream

Tags: typescript, rxjs, subject

I know this is a known behavior as desribed here

- https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93

basic problem is described in the link above, but here is the relevant code (taken from link)

```js
// This is going to behave strangely
const source$ = Observable.interval(1000).share();
const mapped$ = source$.map(x => {
  if (x === 1) {
    throw new Error('oops');
  }
  return x;
});
source$.subscribe(x => console.log('A', x));
mapped$.subscribe(x => console.log('B', x));
source$.subscribe(x => console.log('C', x));
// "A" 0
// "B" 0
// "C" 0
// "A" 1
// Uncaught Error: "oops"
```

an error in a subscription will terminate the whole source stream.

the solution for an Observable is to use `.observeOn(Rx.Scheduler.asap);`

I'm fairly new to the whole reactive programming and I struggle to apply this solution to my `Subject` because subject doesn't support `observeOn`.

But I need a `Subject` because I need to push new values to the steam.

<del>How can I workaround this problem or use `observeOn` with a `Subject`?</del>

`observeOn` returns an `Observable`. But I struggle how to combine `observeOn` with my `Subject`.
**how to use observeOn and still be able to push values to my subject?**

here's the current code (simplified)

```
export class MyClass{

    private messages: Subject<Message> = new Subject<Message>();

    dispatchMessage(message: Message) {

     this.messages.next(message);
}
```

Ideas?

**P.S.**

for anybody using angular (like me), observeOn might have some undesired side effects.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14316

just as additional information for anybody who comes to this question.

Comment: Workaround what problem? The `observeOn` is just an operator that exists on the `Subject` class as well.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow mixed it up. I struggle with the fact that `observeOn` returns an `Observable` and not a `Subject`.

I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you just need to a separate reference to the `Subject` as well as a reference to the chain after you append the `observeOn` operator:

```
const subject$ = new Subject();
const obs$ = subject$.observeOn(...);

obs$.subscribe(...);
subject$.next(...);
```